# Nav element from Foundation 4 does not display on iPhone

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I added a simple `<nav class="top-bar">` element to my page.  It's displaying properly on computers, but on the iPhone I just get a solid black bar with no menu items.  This is the top part of my nav.

```
<nav class="top-bar" style="">
  <ul class="title-area">
    <li class="name"></li>
  </ul>

<section class="top-bar-section">
    <ul class="left">
      <li class="has-dropdown not-click"><a href="#">Orders</a>
        <ul class="dropdown"><li class="title back js-generated"><h5><a href="#">« Back</a></h5></li>
          <li class=""><a href="orders/new.php">Create New</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </section>
</nav>
```

Comment: You are going to need to provide more information. Perhaps a live URL, or relevant CSS that recreates the problem.

Comment: https://www.gargoylesoft.com/nav/

Comment: Replicate this by viewing [Zurb foundation 4 Top Bar](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/top-bar.html) in Opera mobile browser. I tried using the HTC Desire/Galaxy S3 settings. The black example menu bar shows this issue - the three white lines should be showing as the menu icon but do not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the height in your CSS:

```
.top-bar .name {
    height: 45px;
}
```

Specifying a height was causing the `<li>` to render below `<nav>`, and since `overflow:hidden` was set, the `<li>` was not being displayed.

[image]

Comment: Removing height causes the menu to spill out on mobile so the touch toggle no longer works. The framework comes with this height set (in several places).